# How do I run Guava's unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, guava

I have cloned Guava's repository via the following command:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/
```

Because I am not entirely familiar with Guava's structure, I tried the following commands:

```
cd guava-libraries
mvn test
```

Unfortunately, I received the following error (the entire output is available viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/3185180)).

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Guava GWT compatible libs
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/guava/guava/13.0-SNAPSHOT/guava-13.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.google.guava:guava:jar:sources:13.0-SNAPSHOT' in repository sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) com.google.guava:guava:jar:sources:13.0-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.guava -DartifactId=guava -Dversion=13.0-SNAPSHOT -Dclassifier=sources -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.guava -DartifactId=guava -Dversion=13.0-SNAPSHOT -Dclassifier=sources -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.google.guava:guava-gwt:jar:13.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) com.google.guava:guava:jar:sources:13.0-SNAPSHOT

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.google.guava:guava-gwt:jar:13.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
```

How do I run Guava's unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not run just mvn test before complete installation to local repository. Please run first time:

```
mvn clean install
```

Then you can run only `mvn test`. SNAPSHOT's libraries are not available yet in repository.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. A few exceptions were thrown. I will probably investigate it further over the next few days.

Comment: Sorry but the expression you can't run mvn test before complete installation is wrong. Cause you didn't understand the Maven build lifecycle, cause test is coming before install in the lifecycle. Furthermore if mvn test does not work something is wrong with the build.

Comment: @khmarbaise you write with one module maven project. Now imagine - subproject B depends on project A. You did not compile/install project A. Now you are trying to build project B. You will receive error `Unable to find resource groupId:B:jar:sources:version-SNAPSHOT`, because project A has been not uploaded/installed in any repository.

Comment: @ajozwik Having multi module build this works the same. If these projects are indepandent than you are right.

Comment: @khmarbaise **The devil is in the details.** If you see at the log added by @AdamPaynter there is `Unable to find resource 'com.google.guava:guava:jar:sources:13.0-SNAPSHOT' ...` _Guava GWT compatible libs_ needs sources jar (not binary jar). It is builded in `<phase>post-integration-test</phase>`. So if you call just test - the post-integration-test phase is not called and source jar is not deployed to local repository. Download project for details.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a snapshot revision when a release candidate is available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.guava%22%20AND%20a%3a%22guava%22)?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>13.0-rc2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To be clear, I didn't choose to use a snapshot revision. I simply cloned the project and just tried to run its unit tests.